# JDA doesn't support anymore attachments with downloadToFile()?

Tags: java, discord, bots, attachment, discord-jda

I write discord bot with using JDA and i have one important question how to download attachments or work with them? Because my IntelliJ say "Deprecated API usage" for method like **attachment.downloadToFile("name.png);**
So now we shouldn't download users files send in message? Or how we should do it in good way? I search a lot of wiki from JDA and different posts, but everywhere i didn't see, a new option to handle this download files, becasue all methods to download, are "Deprecated API" even method like "**attachment.retrieveInputStream().join()**" retrieveInputStream its too not good way :(

Search a lot on wiki/others pages for more information but nothing found :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [deprecation notice](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.Attachment.html#downloadToFile()) says this:

> **Deprecated.**
>
> Replaced by getProxy(), see FileProxy.downloadToFile(File)

This means you should use `attachment.getProxy().downloadToFile(File)` instead.

Example:

```java
attachment.getProxy().downloadToFile(new File("myimage.png")).thenAccept(file -> {
    System.out.println("Written to file " + file.getAbsolutePath() + ".");
});
```

Or using NIO instead:

```java
attachment.getProxy().downloadToPath().thenAccept(path -> {
    System.out.println("Written to file " + path + ". Total size: " + Files.size(path));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer which a needed